# "Clone in Mac' fails on GitHub. Takes me to download page every time

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, github

I've reinstalled, uninstalled, restarted but "Clone in Mac' on any repository page fails and takes me to the GitHub download page every time.

It was working fine earlier this week but today won't do anything useful.

Any idea why?

Comment: I get the same in Chrome, Safari and Firefox!

Comment: AHHHH I have answered my own question: the trick is TO BE LOGGED IN on the GitHub website.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: you have to be logged in on the GitHub website.